# clojure refactor of calendar vector

Tags: clojure

I have come up with the following function that when given a start date will return 5 vectors, each of 7 days long.

You can think of this as of any calendar month that is generally displayed like this:

```
(defn weeks [start-date]
  (for [week-counter (range 0 35 7)]
    (vec (for [day-counter (range 7)]
      (->
       start-date
       (.clone)
       (.add "days" (+ week-counter day-counter))
       (.format date-format))))))
```

I am new to clojure and I am curious of other ways I could have written this.

Comment: For one thing, a month can span 6 weeks.

Comment: @Pointy for one thing if you actually look at any calendar page, it generally starts at the first monday and ends on the last sunday to give an even feel because months have different amount of days so they generally show  weeks worth of days.  Don't believe me?  Look at any calendar view.  And it is 5 weeks, not 6 so you are wrong on both counts.

Comment: See June 2013 for an example. Of course, traditionally paper calendars would "overload" the last day to squeeze a calendar into 5 weeks. That is, they'd include the last few days overlapping the first few slots in the first week, so that those days would account for the last days of the *previous* month **and** the last days of the target month.

Comment: Or, for that matter, this month, August 2014 - the month spans six weeks, from a Friday to a Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to express it like this:

```
(defn weeks [start-date]
  (letfn [(compose [n] (->  start-date
                           (.clone)
                           (.add "days" n)
                           (.format date-format)))]
    (map vec (partition 7 (map compose (range (* 7 5)))))))
```

But is this what you want? For illustration, if we simplify the `compose` function ...

```
(defn weeks [start-date]
  (letfn [(compose [n] (str start-date " " n))]
    (map vec (partition 7 (map compose (range (* 7 5)))))))
```

... then, for example,

```
(weeks "august")
```

... produces

```
(["august 0"
  "august 1"
  "august 2"
  "august 3"
  "august 4"
  "august 5"
  "august 6"]

   ...

 ["august 28"
  "august 29"
  "august 30"
  "august 31"
  "august 32"
  "august 33"
  "august 34"])
```

I find it hard to think of a use for this.

---

If you want the dates of a month week-by-week, you need to know

- the day of the week that the first of the month falls on - a number
  from 0 to 6;
- the number of days in the month.

A function to generate the pattern is

```
(defn week-pattern [start-day days-in-month]
  (take-while
    (partial some identity)
    (partition 7 (concat (repeat start-day nil)
                         (range days-in-month)
                         (repeat nil)))))
```

For example, June this year started on a Sunday, day 6 (if a week starts on Monday), so spanned six weeks, though only thirty days long:

```
=> (week-pattern 6 30)

((nil nil nil nil nil nil 0)
 (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
 (8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
 (15 16 17 18 19 20 21)
 (22 23 24 25 26 27 28)
 (29 nil nil nil nil nil nil))
```

With this as a template, you can add function arguments to `map` and/or `map-indexed` to play around with the contents at will.

I have followed your usage in counting days of the month from zero instead of from 1 as a real calendar would. If you want to count from 1, replace `(range days-in-month)` with `(range 1 (inc days-in-month))`

---

If you have the choice, consider using a library such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) that treats dates as immutable values.

Comment: [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) is the best Clojure wrapper for Joda-Time.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Thank you: signpost removed.